# How to dynamically modify CSS class using Javascript / jQuery with wrapper?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dynamic

I have an existing html code of table.

eg.

```
<div class="content-entry">
    <table class="old-style" border="3">
        <tr align="middle">
            <td style="font-weight:bold"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I would like to conditionally remove all attributes/classes of the current table  with the injection of a wrapper `<div>` and apply css class style to override the existing table behavior using Javascript / jQuery.

`conten-entry` might have multiple `table` blocks, and I would like to apply the same style change to all of them.

to:

```
<div class="content-entry">
    <div class="responsive-table">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I do this without changing the original html code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use [`.wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/), *wraps an HTML structure around each element in the set of matched elements*

```js
$('.old-style').wrap('<div class="responsive-table"></div>').removeClass().addClass('table table-bordered table-condensed');
```

```css
.responsive-table {
  color: red;
}
.table {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.table-bordered {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.table-condensed>tbody>tr>td,
.table-condensed>tbody>tr>th,
.table-condensed>tfoot>tr>td,
.table-condensed>tfoot>tr>th,
.table-condensed>thead>tr>td,
.table-condensed>thead>tr>th {
  padding: 5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-entry">
  <table class="old-style">
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Note:** Calling `.removeClass` with no arguments will remove all of the item's classes.

Comment: This partially answer my question for applying the wrapper class.  But how do I dynamically remove the existing old classes in `<table>`, and inject the `class="table table-bordered table-condensed"` inside the `<div class="content-entry">`?  I've modified the original question with a more detailed example.

Comment: Another question regarding to `.wrap`, does the order of the matched classes matter?

Comment: No, It is just a selector like all other selectors.. You have the option of `.addClass` and `.removeClass` to deal with `classes`..

Comment: Your code works for the specific instance of `class="old-style"`.  I might have multiple classes, is there a way I can globally remove all classes of the `<table>`elements enclosed in `<div class="content-entry">` and apply the new classes throughout?  I might have multiple `table` blocks and each may have different default class/attributes.

Comment: Updated post will help!

Comment: One more scenario, what if the `<table>` doesn't have a class to begin with?  How can I perform the same classes injection and wrapper `<div>`?