# How to conditionally modify HTML/CSS classes using PHP with Regex?

Tags: php, html, css, regex, dynamic

I have the a block of HTML code read into a variable `$content`:

```
<div class="entry">
    <table class="old-style1 old-style2">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I would like to remove all classes/attributes of the existing `<table>` element and replace it with new classes and another `<div>` wrapper.

to:

```
<div class="entry">
    <div class="table-wrapper">
        <table class="new-style1 new-style2">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </table>
</div>
```

I might have multiple `table` elements within the `<div class="entry">` block.  And I would like to apply the same style modification to all of them.

How can I get the done in the PHP level using `RegEx` or other methods?

Comment: Sure duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36950368/how-to-dynamically-modify-css-class-using-javascript-jquery-with-wrapper

Comment: PHP approach is a totally different question than javascript implementation.  What I'm trying to achieve might not be possible without RegEx or a proper parser as suggested in the first comment.  jQuery does get the job done at run-time in a limited way, but if the browser's javascript was turned off, the layout design will be a mess. I'm seeking for a most efficient and simple solution instead of analyzing all different scenarios w/ multiple if statements. In the first comment, there are lots of useful reading, yet I can't manage to give all of them a try, any comment on which is recommended?